# MysqlDump to CSV format. (Enclosed string fields, first description row, no sql files)

Tags: csv, export, mysql, dump

I would like to know mysqldump parameters in order to get in a directory, every table in CSV format (, separated + a description first row). I don' want any other files like .sql.

For example, if I have only the following table in the schema

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(320) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In the output I would get only a user.csv file like this

```
id;name;lastname;email
1;"Mark";"Lenders";"mark@gmail.com"
...
```

If possible, I also want to enclose only varchar fields.

I use this mysqldump call

```
mysqldump -u root -p -t -T /tmp dbschema --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=;
```

But I still have these mistakes:

- I don't get the first description row with the fields of the table (column names header)
- I get .txt files instead of .csv
- I get .sql empty files appart from .txt
- The fields enclosed by " are not only the varchar ones, but also the numerics fields

Server has a Debian6 operating system.

Thanks!!

Comment: What about SELECT...INTO OUTFILE command? It allows to stora data in CSV file. ...but this command does not write header information, just data.

Comment: SELECT INTO OUTFILE is not the best solution becouse I want every table to be dumped, so I would have to make lots of selects that I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: I have added an answer with sp which may help you.

Comment: mysqldump is a SELECT statement after all, it make no differences between SELECT INTO OUTFILE vs mysqldump

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE write_tables_to_csv()
BEGIN

  DECLARE ts, tn  VARCHAR(64);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_schema
                              , table_name
                         FROM
                           information_schema.tables
                         WHERE
                           table_schema = 'test'
                           AND table_name LIKE 'table1%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur;
  REPEAT
    FETCH cur INTO ts, tn;
    IF NOT done THEN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', ts, '.', tn, ' INTO OUTFILE ''', tn, '.csv'' FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ''"''');
      PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
      EXECUTE stmt1;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
    END IF;
  UNTIL done
  END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This procedure reads table names, generates SELECT statements and executes them.
Change the condition for your schema and tables.

**EDIT**

Also, you clould use Data Export tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). It alows to export some tables in any format at once. CSV format writes column header, and string fields are enclosed by specified symbol.

Comment: Thanks! It is a good answer. I have already known this possibility, however I would like to know if there is a simpler way by using mysqldump. However, does this procedure avoid the mistakes i asked before like the first description row with column names?

Comment: To enclose string values you can use 'FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY' option (procedure is edited). About column header - SELECT command does not write it.

Comment: Thanks again Devart! So, is there no solution to get the headings in the first row? It must be! :-). (I'd prefer not to need third party software)